# File tag in HTML

Tags: php

I used

```
<input type="file" name="datafile" class="dropdown" required/>
```

in my HTML form. I select one file from any other location than `www` directory. I get one PHP error like

> faild to open stream : no such file and directory available in
>   `c:/wamp/www/myproject/abc.php`

Comment: can u post some of your php code ?

Comment: Can you show us the php code you're using to call c:/wamp/www/myproject/abc.php ?

Answer (score 1):

try using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form when you are uploading files. without the code, its hard to tell, why that specific error has occurred. So, please post your code with your question if the error still persists